# Bitwise & operator returns 255

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using bitwise & operator but instead of 1 and 0 result I am getting 255 and 0.What could be the reason?
The code is

```
 cv::Mat TL_k_idx = ((orientation_map.col(0)<=(quad_coords[0]+quad_coords[2])/2) & (orientation_map.col(1)<=(quad_coords[1]+quad_coords[3])/2));
cout<<TL_k_idx;

The output of TL_k_idx is:
255 255 255 255 0 0............
```

The orientation_map is of Mat data type,the quad_coords is an array.What am I doing wrong?

And while using logical operator && I get an error

```
error: no match for ‘operator&&’ in ‘cv::operator<=(const cv::Mat&, double)((double)((*
(quad_coords) + *(quad_coords + 8u)) / 2)) && cv::operator<=(const cv::Mat&, double)((double)((*
(quad_coords + 4u) + *(quad_coords + 12u)) / 2))’|
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not expect a bitwise **and** to be 0 or 1.

Here's how something could be 255:

```
a = 255 & 255 // then a = 255;
```

Here's a couple examples

```
Example 1    11111111 & 11111111 = 11111111 or 255

Example 2: 01010101 & 00000111 = 101 or 5.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: Os sorry then I think I shud use the logical &&.I tried to use logical AND && but it gives an 'error no match for operator&&'

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing operations on native (raw) C/C++ types and OpenCV classes.

From your question, I understand that you want to create a column vector the same size as the first and second column of your orientation map, then fill it with some result. here is a proposal:

```
/* Create the output as the copy of the 1st col */
cv::Mat TL_k_idx = orientation_map.col(0).clone(); 

/* Now, fill it with the correct result by looping over the elements */
for (row = 0; row < TL_k_idx.rows; ++i)
{
  float col0_elem = TL_k_idx.at<float>(row);  // I assume you have float data;
                                              // Change according to your type.
  TL_k_idx.at<float>(row) = ( col0_elem <=(quad_coords[0]+quad_coords[2])/2) ) &&
                            ( orientation_map.col(1).at<float>(row)<=(quad_coords[1]+quad_coords[3])/2) );
}
```

This version is not optimized (I would use direct pointers to the data for example in my own code) but the purpose here is to demonstrate various and easy ways to handle matrix data in OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV always gives 255 and 0 as result of logical operations, it uses assumption, of C/C++ that all that is not 0 is "true". It userful, when you need visualize results. If you need 0 and 1, just do TL_k_idx/=255; and you'll get what you want.